# Cannot find module 'passport'

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker-compose, passport.js

I am trying to start project with using Docker Compose at Ubuntu (16.04 LTS). However, I have this issue with 'passport' module

```
api_1            | [nodemon] 1.11.0
api_1            | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
api_1            | [nodemon] watching: *.*
api_1            | [nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
api_1            | Debugger listening on 127.0.0.1:5858
api_1            | module.js:472
api_1            |     throw err;
api_1            |     ^
api_1            | 
api_1            | Error: Cannot find module 'passport'
api_1            |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename  (module.js:470:15)
api_1            |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
api_1            |     at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
api_1            |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
api_1            |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/auth.js:4:16)
api_1            |     at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
api_1            |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
api_1            |     at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
api_1            |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
api_1            |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
api_1            |     at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
api_1            |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
api_1            |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:3:14)
api_1            |     at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
api_1            |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
api_1            |     at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
api_1            | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes 
                                before starting...
```

The main thing is that:

1) Docker is running everything (and sets everything up, as mentioned in Dockerfile)

2) There is passport dependency in package.json, in /app (where the server is launched).

3) Passport as well as Node with npm are globally installed in Ubuntu (even though, Docker must set up all of these itself).

4) I have `const passport = require('passport');` in the files where it is used.

Thus, I suspect that there are problems with some folder or file permissions (maybe even Docker's). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

I just had to completely reinstall the docker and docker-compose and everything worked perfect.

**Update:** Another (probably, main) reason was that my Internet provider was blocking NPM, this is why I could not download (somehow) some of the packages. Thus, it worked out when I connected to another WiFi network.